# Is it Possible to Have Docker Compose Read from AWS Secrets Manager?

Tags: bash, docker, docker-compose, aws-secrets-manager

I currently have a bash script that "simulates" an ECS task by spinning up 3 containers.  Some of the containers pull their secrets and configuration overrides from Secrets Manager directly(e.g. it's baked into the container code), while others have configuration overrides that are being done with Docker Environment variables which requires the Secrets be retrieve first from ASM, exported to variables, then starting the container with the environment variables just exported.  This works fine and this is done just for developers to test locally on their workstations.  We do not deploy with Docker-Compose.  The current bash script makes calls out to AWS and exports the values to Environment variables.

However, I would like to use Docker Compose going forward.  The question I have is "Is there a way for Docker Compose to call out to AWS and get the secrets?"

I don't see a native way to do this with Docker Compose, so I am thinking of going out and getting ALL the secrets for ALL the containers.  So, my current script would be modified to do this:

1. The Bash the script would get all the secrets and export these values to environment variables.
2. The script would then call the Docker-compose yaml and reference the exported variables created in step 1 above.

It would be nice if I didn't have to use the bash script at all, but I know of no intrinsic way of pulling secrets from Secrets Manager from the Docker-Compose yaml.  Is this possible?

Comment: No, docker (for which docker-compose is just a very thin wrapper) doesn't have any intrinsic support for AWS secrets manager (or vault, or azure secrets, or bitwarden, or any of the other various secrets managers out there). You'll see support for things like this in higher-level orchestration tools (e.g., one can use the [External Secrets](https://github.com/external-secrets/kubernetes-external-secrets) with Kubernetes to expose secrets from AWS secrets manager to containers as files or environment variables).